# Why does this hydrangea have spots?

Tags: diagnosis, hydrangea, blackberry

Why does this hydrangea have spots?

My blackberry has similar spots. Might they be related?

[image]

Comment: Anything going on underneath the leaves? Turn them over and check to see what's there....

Comment: @Bamboo I just looked and the bottom of the leaves just looked normal. No insects or anything of that nature.